# Combining rows from the same data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code that create a new column to combine two rows together. The idea is to add the row when there is NA.

The new column will be the "EventDate

Here is a sample data frame:

```
Id    SDate         CDate                EventDate
101   2013-03-27    NA                   2013-03-27
101   2013-05-09    NA                   2013-05-09
101   NA            2013-05-30           2013-05-30
101   NA            2013-07-26           2013-07-26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate(EventDate = coalesce(SDate, CDate))
```